# Problema jquery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

Estou utilizando um formulário para preencher itens de uma lista dinamicamente.
Eu limpo os campos do formulário ao inserir os itens da lista no ato adição de itens.

Problema:

Quando realizo o submit para gravar, o help do Razor `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` intervém não permitindo o submit, porque é necessário gravar os itens da lista do objeto pai.

Solução a ser encontrada:

Quando realizar o submit do formulário. Seta os campo do do formulário com required false.

Estava tipo querendo manipular a biblioteca `$("#form").validate();`

Estava pesquisando sobre essa função, mas ainda consegui com que funcionasse.

Código:

```
$(".btnGravarEmpenho").on("click", function () {
    $("#formConvenio").submit();
});

//estava testando essa função
$("#formConvenio").validate({
    rules: {
        input: {
            required: false
        }
    },
    messages: {
        input: {
            required: "fsfafafa"
        }
    },
    ignore: "",
    errorClass: 'fieldError',
    onkeyup: false,
    onblur: false,
    errorElement: 'label',
    submitHandler: function () {
        alert("alert");
    }
});
```

É claro que as propriedades que tiver os anotations de validaçao irá refletir nas views e controller. Mas eu preciso ainda da validação ao inserir o item, mas não submit. Porque o que o vale é a lista do objeto.

Comment: Você pode postar uma amostra do código?

Comment: Que tal não chamar o submit do form e fazer o post dos dados manualmente com `$.post();`?

Comment: Pode ser sim uma soluççao Iurístona. Evitar de ultizar o submit do formulário. Ou até o ajax também seria a solução para enviar as informaçoes ao servidor.

Comment: O código chega a cair no *Controller*? Se sim, você consegue ler o valor do `ModelState`?